# Actions on web elements not working when executed from command prompt

Tags: selenium

i am not getting any error in the log file to resolve the problem. the code is entering in to the homepage.java and starting with login method, however txtusername is not populated with the values. working fine in eclipse. this is happening when executing from command line

```
D:\Workspaces\test> java -cp 
  "D:\Workspaces\test\bin;D:\Workspaces\test\lib\*;C:\Users\me\plugins\*" 
  org.testng.TestNG D:\Workspaces\test\testng1.xml
```

```java
public class TestMain extends DriverInstance {
    HomePage homePage;
    WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeMethod
    public void launchAppication()  {
        driver = launchBrowser();
        launchURL();
        homePage = PageFactory.initElements(driver, HomePage.class);
    }

    @Test(groups = { "functest", "Login" }, testName = "RTSFS-21: Verify Login with Correct username and correct Password", priority = 1)
    public void verifyLogin_CorrectLoginCredentials() {     
        try {
            System.out.println("hello this is test method after try block");
            //Thread.sleep(5000);
            homePage.login(driver, "Login");
            System.out.println("hello this is test method after login method");
            // homePage.pageWait();
            //Thread.sleep(5000);
            homePage.validateURL("www.xyz.com", "Verify Login with Correct username and correct Password");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.fail("exception : " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

This is the homepage.java

```java
public void login(WebDriver driver, String elementName) 
{       
    JsonReader jr = new JsonReader();

    try
    {
        System.out.println("hello this is login block");
        txtUsername.sendKeys(jr.GetElementValue(elementName+".Username"));
        System.out.println("hello this is text username");
    }
```

execution displays the message hello this is login block" and abruptly ends.

Comment: On your login method, catch the exception and print to console. This should provide insight in to why it is failing.

Comment: no exception is being printed.